# Purpose of Time Condition Field

Tags: magento-1, adminhtml, import, adminform

I have no clue what is the purpose of time_condition field in admin page.

Class File:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Import ... {
    public function getElementHtml() {
        ...
        $('time_condition').value = '_' + conditionNameElement.value + '/' + Math.random();
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried to search all ***.php, *.phtml, *.js** files for this string "time_condition", the result seems no server or client codes using this field. Is this field useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a place where it is used.

Go to System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods -> Table Rates.

Change scope to website.

Now you will see Import fields in configuration list.

This field uses `$('time_condition').value`.

You can open browser console and search for it.

So I found that when you change "Condition" field, the value of

```
<input id="time_condition" type="hidden" name="groups[tablerate][fields][import][value]" value="_package_value/0.8849172815680504">
```

is changed. After it is saved to `core_config_data` by `carriers/tablerate/import` path.

But still this config value is never used. At least I did not found any exact occurrences.

Comment: Oleksii, appreciate for your findings. Exactly as you said that value was changed when onchange event occurred on condition field. I did a check on database using below query, seems that value never store in database. 

`select * from CORE_CONFIG_DATA where path like 'carriers/tablerate%';`

Comment: It will be stored if you save(at least once) config for shipping methods.

Comment: The value corresponds to uploaded file name `INSERT INTO core_config_data
(config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value)
VALUES(1036, 'websites', 1, 'carriers/tablerate/import', 'tablerates (1).csv');`

Comment: After file select before saving change "Condition" field.

Comment: Yep, I did it before saving =)

Comment: Can I still somehow help you?

Comment: Your finding above is more than enough and very helpful.